# OnUp event on GestureDetector

Tags: android, event-listener, gesturedetector

My question is simple, where's the onUp event when implementing a `GestureListener`?

I has a lot of events on the gesturedetector, and cannot just consume the onUp event of the listener, cause one of events are the `onSingleTapConfirmed` that needs it.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what do you want to do here, but there is `onSingleTapUp` in `GestureListener` that might be what you are looking for. It is fired on a complete tap, though, not swiping. For that you could just process the "raw" `onTouchEvent` of view/activity without passing it to `GestureDetector`.

Comment: onSingleTapUp is fired when a tap is done. I need DOWN, then MOVE, and end with UP.

Comment: That's `onFling`, except that you don't get the MOVE events. If you need them, I guess your only option is to handle `onTouchEvent` directly.

Comment: Hey @MarcosVasconcelos. I see that you solved this somehow?  I'm trying to do the same thing and onFling() doesn't work for me as the below answer suggests.  Can you explain how you fixed this?  Thanks.

Comment: Use the onTouchEvent approach.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try using `onFling()`. Seems like a weird name but for me, it works as the `onUp()` method would logically work. Or try this method...

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {

  Log.v("ADAM", "ontouch: " + me.getAction());

  if(me.getAction() == 0){
    Log.v("ADAM", "Down");
  }
  else if (me.getAction() == 1) {
    Log.v("ADAM", "Up");
  }
  else if (me.getAction() == 2) {
    Log.v("ADAM", "Scroll");
  }
  boolean detectedUp = event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP;
  if (!mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event) && detectedUp) {
    return onUp(event);
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I solve it by reading the vent before passing it to the GestureListener (the onFling is absolute useless)

Comment: Great answer, just wanted to add that the onFling is not entirely useless - it helps you differentiate between a scroll and a swipe. Though you often get a fling when you think you're just lifting your finger, you can screen out the insignificant ones by checking the velocity parameters in the onFling handler.

Comment: The OnFling event does not always occur when you do a swipe.  Most notably, if you swipe but stop moving your finger for a moment before lifting it, there's often no event.

Answer (score 8):

I fixed it by reading the `Action event` before I pass it to the `GestureListener`

```
img.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
      if (arg1.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
          && !getDocument().isScaled()) 
        img.notifyUp();
      return gestures.onTouchEvent(arg1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

The other answers can solve the question,maybe they work good,but I don't think those are good solutions.
Because we should deal with the event in a single moudle,so that we can be esaier to maintain or expand the code.
(By the way, don not use `onFilng()` ,if your finger move slowly on the screen,`onFilng()` wouldn't work)
So,my solution is **rewriting the GestureDetector**:

```
public class ModifyGestureDetector extends GestureDetector {

    MyGestureListener myGestureListener;

    public ModifyGestureDetector(Context context, OnGestureListener listener) {
        super(context, listener);
        init(listener);
    }

    void init(OnGestureListener listener){
        if (listener instanceof MyGestureListener){
            myGestureListener = (MyGestureListener) listener;
        }
    }

    //u can write something more complex as long as u need
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP 
            && myGestureListener != null){
            myGestureListener.onUp(ev);
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    public interface MyGestureListener{
        public void onUp(MotionEvent ev);
    }
}
```

And the listener:

```
public class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
        implements ModifyGestureDetector.MyGestureListener {


    @Override
    public void onUp(MotionEvent ev) {
        //do what u want
    }
}
```

: )

Answer (score 2):

Have you returned true from the other events you consume in your GestureDetector.OnGestureListener?  I had this problem and it turns out if you return false, the system assumes you aren't interested and stops passing you events, so you miss the up!