# Android - Creating an analogue type animated image for movement

Tags: java, android, xml, game-physics

I am looking to create an analogue like controller in order to move my character within my xml layout (this will look similar to that on a PlayStation or Xbox controller - the circular analogue).

My first plan was to simple have an Image View and place 4 transparent buttons over the Image View to allow for movement, however this is a bit dull and would like to get really creative with it, however I am struggling to find any kind of documentation and not really sure where to start.

Essentially, the functionality that I am after is an image which looks like an analogue (see below), the user can then press down on and move around with animation, which will trigger the relevant positional movement. Ideally i would also like to have this so that is the user simply clicks to the right on the analogue it automatically animates and then triggers the right movement.

[image]

I am not sure if this is possible at all, I require this to be implemented within my xml layout or can be created programmatically if that is easier.

Comment: Are you looking to recreate a genuine looking analogue stick or do you just want the centre circle to follow your thumb around the stick radius?

Comment: @dev in theory I want to recreate a genuine looking analogue, however not too fussed how it looks as long as to the user it seems like they are moving an analogue around to move left, right, up & down.

Comment: @dev further to the movement if the user holds the analogue to the right, I would require a small 1 second gap before my move function gets called.

Comment: You should make a animated gif image and Play using Movie class.

Comment: @Biraj, that would not really work as I still need to detect the position the user has chosen to move. Then call my move class.

Comment: Just did the Part 1 of creating a Playstation knob http://www.sherif.mobi/2013/09/android-custom-view-playstation-knob.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

please see the **LAST EDIT**

```
----------------------------------------------
```

You have to implement the GestureDetector.OnGestureListener interface, and use the onDown, onScroll methods to detect the gestures, and then  using the onDraw(Canvas c) method of your view , redraw the bitmap of your analogue after modifying it's position (and transform it with matrix if you want)

You can also use the onTouchEvent like in this answer : 
[OnUp event on GestureDetector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722719/onup-event-on-gesturedetector)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**EDIT**

Here is a try, without using bitmaps, just drawCircle method : 

[image]
 
it's not too complicated, 
i wrote it fast so there is certainly improvements to do,
 but it works quite well as is :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class AnalogueView extends View {

    float x,y;
    double r,t;
    int cx, cy,w,h;
    final int RADIUS = 20;
    Paint black = new Paint();
    Paint grey = new Paint();
    Paint white = new Paint();

    private int toDo;

    public AnalogueView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        black.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        grey.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        white.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        black.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        white.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        grey.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        cx = w/2;
        cy = h/2;
        x = cx;y=cy;
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        drawMyStuff(canvas);
        switch (toDo) {
        case 1:
            center();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    private void drawMyStuff(final Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, w/2, black);
        canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, w/2-5, grey);
        canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, w/2-10, black);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, RADIUS+2, white);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, RADIUS, grey);
    }

//  n2p : normal to polar coordinates conversion
//  p2n : polar to normal coordinates conversion
//  R : distance to polar center 
//  T : polar angle
    double n2pR(double x, double y){
        return distance(x,y,cx,cy);
    }

    double n2pT(double x, double y){
        return Math.atan2((y-cy),(x-cx));
    }

    double p2nX(double r, double t){
        return r*Math.cos(t) + cx;
    }



    double p2nY(double r, double t){
        return r*Math.sin(t) + cy;
    }

    double n2pR(){
        return distance(x,y,cx,cy);
    }

    double n2pT(){
        return Math.atan2((y-cy),(x-cx));
    }

    double p2nX(){
        return r*Math.cos(t) + cx;
    }

    double p2nY(){
        return r*Math.sin(t) + cy;
    }

    double distance(double x1 , double y1, double x2, double y2 ){
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1-x2, 2)+Math.pow(y1-y2, 2));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
            updatePosition(event);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
            updatePosition(event);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
            toDo = 1; 
            center(); 
            break;
        default :break;

        }

        return true;
    }

    private void center(){
        if(r>15){
            r-=15;
        }else{
            toDo=0;
            r=0;
        }
        x = (float) p2nX();
        y= (float) p2nY();
        invalidate();
    }

    void updatePosition(MotionEvent e){
        r= Math.min(w/2-RADIUS, n2pR(e.getX(),e.getY()));
        t = n2pT(e.getX(),e.getY());
        x = (float) p2nX();
        y =(float) p2nY();

        invalidate();
    }
}
```

here is how to add it to a layout  :

```
<yourpackage.AnalogueView
    android:id="@+id/analogueView1"
    android:layout_width="80px"
    android:layout_height="80px"
     />
```

And for detecting the different analogue events you can add a Listener with the methods definitions you need, and use the interface within the AnalogView, then when you want to implement a behavior for the AnalogView you just add an implementation to the inteface by calling a setter for the listener (it's like the setOnClickListener for a Button). This way you will have an  entirely encapsulated AnalogView that you can reuse in any other app.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**LAST EDIT** : handling events with listener :

I embedded a Listener with the AnalogueView , now you can use it the same way you use the OnClickListener for a button,

use the setOnMoveListener method to provide your implementation of the two methods :

```
onMaxMoveInDirection(double polar_angle_of_direction) and 
onHalfMoveInDirection(double polar_angle_of_direction)
```

Here is the new code for AnalogueView (no big modifications, just the interface definition, the moveListener field and fire the actions in the updatePosition) :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class AnalogueView extends View {

    OnMoveListener moveListener;


    float x,y;
    double r,t;
    int cx, cy,w,h;
    final int RADIUS = 20;
    Paint black = new Paint();
    Paint grey = new Paint();
    Paint white = new Paint();

    private int toDo;

    public AnalogueView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        black.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        grey.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        white.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        black.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        white.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        grey.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        cx = w/2;
        cy = h/2;
        x = cx;y=cy;
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        drawMyStuff(canvas);
        switch (toDo) {
        case 1:
            center();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }

    private void drawMyStuff(final Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, w/2, black);
        canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, w/2-5, grey);
        canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, w/2-10, black);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, RADIUS+2, white);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, RADIUS, grey);
    }

//  n2p : normal to polar coordinates conversion
//  p2n : polar to normal coordinates conversion
//  R : distance to polar center 
//  T : polar angle
    double n2pR(double x, double y){
        return distance(x,y,cx,cy);
    }

    double n2pT(double x, double y){
        return Math.atan2((y-cy),(x-cx));
    }

    double p2nX(double r, double t){
        return r*Math.cos(t) + cx;
    }



    double p2nY(double r, double t){
        return r*Math.sin(t) + cy;
    }

    double n2pR(){
        return distance(x,y,cx,cy);
    }

    double n2pT(){
        return Math.atan2((y-cy),(x-cx));
    }

    double p2nX(){
        return r*Math.cos(t) + cx;
    }

    double p2nY(){
        return r*Math.sin(t) + cy;
    }

    double distance(double x1 , double y1, double x2, double y2 ){
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1-x2, 2)+Math.pow(y1-y2, 2));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
            updatePosition(event);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
            updatePosition(event);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
            toDo = 1; 
            center(); 
            break;
        default :break;

        }

        return true;
    }

    private void center(){
        if(r>15){
            r-=15;
        }else{
            toDo=0;
            r=0;
        }
        x = (float) p2nX();
        y= (float) p2nY();
        invalidate();
    }

    void updatePosition(MotionEvent e){
        r= Math.min(w/2-RADIUS, n2pR(e.getX(),e.getY()));
        t = n2pT(e.getX(),e.getY());
        x = (float) p2nX();
        y =(float) p2nY();


        if(moveListener != null)
            if(r == w/2-RADIUS)
                moveListener.onMaxMoveInDirection(t);
            else if(r >= w/4-RADIUS/2)
                moveListener.onHalfMoveInDirection(t);

        invalidate();
    }

    public void setOnMoveListener(OnMoveListener listener){
        moveListener =listener;
    }

    public interface OnMoveListener{
        public void onHalfMoveInDirection(double polarAngle);
        public void onMaxMoveInDirection(double polarAngle);
    }
}
```

And here is how to provide an implementation :

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.analog.AnalogueView.OnMoveListener;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    AnalogueView analogue;
    TextView showMoveEvent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        showMoveEvent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showMoveEvent);
        analogue = (AnalogueView) findViewById(R.id.analogueView1);
        analogue.setOnMoveListener(new OnMoveListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMaxMoveInDirection(double polarAngle) {
                showMoveEvent.setText("max move in "+polarAngle+" direction");
            }

            @Override
            public void onHalfMoveInDirection(double polarAngle) {
                showMoveEvent.setText("half move in "+polarAngle+" direction");

            }
        });
    }



}
```

Result : showing events in a text field :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, I will be looking at implementing it on Friday, I will let you know how it comes along and accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Hi, I have implemented your code and the analogue images is appearing perfectly. Just trying to work out how can I detect where the user has selected so that I can trigger the relevant move. Essentially I want to add an imaginary X through the analogue and when it in the 50% closest to the edge the move is called. I understand i need to use the OnTouch just not quite sure how to detect the position and then my function move(1). Thanks

Comment: here is how you should do it : whenever the analog exceed 50% in a certain direction it will fire the move action in a listener, i'll do it know and edit the answer,

Comment: Ok thanks, will accept the answer and award you the bounty once I get it working.

Comment: of course you can add methods definitions in the interface to handle more events

Comment: Exactly what I was after, final question, is their a way that I can stop the onMove triggering so often. I essentially only want to check for the position once every 1 seconds.

Comment: maybe instead of sampling it in time you should sample it in space,
ie you store the old (x,y) position, and you do not fire the events unless the new (x,y) position is greatly different from the old one (see also Kalman filter for calculating the average value on n last positions)

Comment: That would work to an extend, however if the user were to hold the analogue down then they would move down very quickly. This is why I want to add the time delay, so the position would not really help here?

Comment: every time the onMaxMove is fired you will slightly change the position of whatever you are controlling with the analog, the delta-position you will increment or decrement is the speed , so you can controll the movement's speed by deciding the delta-position.

You can also use a Kalman filter as i said and test on the average value of r in the n last executions of updatePosition so that the variation will be smooth , (n could be 100 or 1000 you should test it )

Comment: I will look into this, although never used a Kalman filter before. The movement speed does not need to be smooth, it is essentially a block by block movement, the amount of movement is always set. Is their an easier way to do this?

Comment: ok i see, if it's a block by block as you say then forget about the kalmann filter (it was not a good idea after all). Actually the analogue is more adapted to analog actions, the block by block is a discrete actions, so it would be more appropriate to use a discrete controller (like the cross in playstation) 
But here is a workaround to do it with this analogue, put a counter in the updatePosition, and every 100  reset the conter and fire the listeners actions, 
try it and test different values for the counter until you get something acceptable